# Rsync: Figure out how many files are new and how many updated

Tags: bash, rsync

Is it possible to get stats on which files rsync modified and which ones were completely new in the destination?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `man rsync`:

```
--ignore-existing       skip updating files that exist on receiver
```

You can also use the flags"

```
-v, --verbose               increase verbosity
-P                          equivalent to --partial --progress
```

To see which files have been changed and what is happening.